# how to save information from data table button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using data table to show my information from database.I want to save user information when a user save excel or csv or pdf from the table. I have written a function to save my user information. How can i save them when a button is clicked.How can i solve this problem?? TIA

function:

```
 public  function save_export(){
    $data = array(
    $sdob=date('Y-m-d'),
    'export_date'=>$sdob,
    $modifiedby = $this->session->userdata('user_name'),
    'user_name' => $modifiedby,
    'export_tb_name'=>$this->input->post('')

    );

   $this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 
    }
```

datatable js:

```
<script>
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pull-right").on('click', '.glyphicon-chevron-up, .glyphicon-chevron-down', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
        });
        $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
        $.datepicker.regional[""].changeMonth = true;
        $.datepicker.regional[""].changeYear = true;
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
        oTable = $('#player_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                 "stateSave": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "sServerMethod": "GET",
                "sAjaxSource": site_url + "backend/players/ajaxData",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, - 1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                tableTools: {
                "sRowSelect": "multi",
        "sSwfPath": site_url + "js/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
               "aButtons": [
                   "select_all", "select_none",
                   "copy",
                   "csv",
                   "xls",
                   {
                       "sExtends": "pdf",
                       "sTitle": "Report Name",
                       "sPdfMessage": "Summary Info",
                       "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                       "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig, flash) {
                           customName = 'Playerlist' + ".pdf";
                           flash.setFileName(customName);
                           this.fnSetText(flash,
                                   "title:" + 'Hurrycane' + "\n" +
                                   "message:" + 'Player List' + "\n" +
                                   "colWidth:" + this.fnCalcColRatios(oConfig) + "\n" +
                                   "orientation:" + oConfig.sPdfOrientation + "\n" +
                                   "size:" + oConfig.sPdfSize + "\n" +
                                   "--/TableToolsOpts--\n" +
                                   this.fnGetTableData(oConfig)
                                   );
                       }
                   },
                   "print"
               ],        
        },
                "aoColumns": [
                {"bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
                {"bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
                {"bVisible": true, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false}]
    });
    oTable.columnFilter({
        sRangeSeparator: "&%&",
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
            aoColumns: [
                {type: "text"},
                {type: "text"},

                null
            ]
        });    
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to perform some AJAX inside of a click() event. Need to see more of an example. Something like `$("#player_table button").click(function(){ $.get("saveInfo.php", "{'link': $(this).prop('id')}");});`

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have used ajax post for saving.

Answer (score 0):

The function form_open should help you : 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open#form_open

Answer (score -1):

By using this code you can't save a data in CSV or Excel file but you can save in a PDF file.

CodeIgniter is providing one library, it will convert HTML code into .pdf file.

So first display all data in HTML page using table and then convert it to PDF file.

```
$this->load->library('cezpdf');
```

http://www.code2learn.com/2012/03/generating-tabulated-pdf-file-from.html

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Generate-PDF-Files-from-Database-using-CodeIgniter/74395